# Issues with rewrite I cant figure out

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make my links a more userfriendly, right now theyre like

```
http://localhost/messages/?s=whatever
to
http://localhost/messages/whatever
```

But only the RewriteRule that comes first works, so right now only messages works all the other give me `Internal Server Error`. But if I put `RewriteRule ^users/([^/]*)$ /users/index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` above messages rewrite rule only going to `/users/view` works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^messages/([^/]*)$ /messages/index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]*)$ /users/index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^notes/([^/]*)$ /notes/index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]*)$ /posts/index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that your rewriteRules are rewriting a url back to itself.
forexample The regex pattern  **^users/([^/]*)$** matches /users/index.php and rewrites it to /user/index.php, that is why you are getting 500 ISE.

You need to exclude dot ([^./]*) in your pattern so that target path can not match the pattern.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^messages/([^/.]*)$ /messages/index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^users/([^/.]*)$ /users/index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^notes/([^./]*)$ /notes/index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/.]*)$ /posts/index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: My hero i didnt think any one would answer!